# How to access sparse matrix elements?

Tags: python, scipy

```
type(A)
<class 'scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix'>
A.shape
(8529, 60877)
print A[0,:]
  (0, 25)   1.0
  (0, 7422) 1.0
  (0, 26062)    1.0
  (0, 31804)    1.0
  (0, 41602)    1.0
  (0, 43791)    1.0
print A[1,:]
  (0, 7044) 1.0
  (0, 31418)    1.0
  (0, 42341)    1.0
  (0, 47125)    1.0
  (0, 54376)    1.0
print A[:,0]
  #nothing returned
```

Now what I don't understand is that `A[1,:]` should select elements from the 2nd row, yet I get elements from the 1st row via `print A[1,:]`. Also, `print A[:,0]` should return the first column but I get nothing printed. Why?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`A[1,:]` is itself a sparse matrix with shape (1, 60877).  *This* is what you are printing, and it has only one row, so all the row coordinates are 0.

For example:

```
In [41]: a = csc_matrix([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 10, 11], [0, 0, 0, 99]])

In [42]: a.todense()
Out[42]: 
matrix([[ 1,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 10, 11],
        [ 0,  0,  0, 99]], dtype=int64)

In [43]: print(a[1, :])
  (0, 2)    10
  (0, 3)    11

In [44]: print(a)
  (0, 0)    1
  (1, 2)    10
  (1, 3)    11
  (2, 3)    99

In [45]: print(a[1, :].toarray())
[[ 0  0 10 11]]
```

You can select columns, but if there are no nonzero elements in the column, nothing is displayed when it is output with `print`:

```
In [46]: a[:, 3].toarray()
Out[46]: 
array([[ 0],
       [11],
       [99]])

In [47]: print(a[:,3])
  (1, 0)    11
  (2, 0)    99

In [48]: a[:, 1].toarray()
Out[48]: 
array([[0],
       [0],
       [0]])

In [49]: print(a[:, 1])


In [50]:
```

The last `print` call shows no output because the column `a[:, 1]` has no nonzero elements.

Comment: is it not possible to select columns?

Comment: @bizso09: Yes.  But if there are no nonzero values in the column `A[:,0]`, the print statement doesn't print anything.  I'll add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 34):

To answer your title's question using a different technique than your question's details:

`csc_matrix` gives you the method `.nonzero()`.

Given:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.sparse.csc import csc_matrix
>>> 
>>> row = np.array( [0, 1, 3])
>>> col = np.array( [0, 2, 3])
>>> data = np.array([1, 4, 16])
>>> A = csc_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(4, 4))
```

You can access the indices poniting to non-zero data by:

```
>>> rows, cols = A.nonzero()
>>> rows
array([0, 1, 3], dtype=int32)
>>> cols
array([0, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
```

Which you can then use to access your data, without ever needing to make a dense version of your sparse matrix:

```
>>> [((i, j), A[i,j]) for i, j in zip(*A.nonzero())]
[((0, 0), 1), ((1, 2), 4), ((3, 3), 16)]
```

Comment: Thank you, latest information is really useful.

Answer (score 5):

If it is for calculating TFIDF score using `TfidfTransformer`, yu can get the IDF by  `tfidf.idf_`. Then the sparse array name, say 'a', `a.toarray().`

`toarray` returns an ndarray; `todense` returns a matrix. If you want a matrix, use `todense`; otherwise, use `toarray`.

Answer (score 2):

I fully acknowledge all the other given answers. This is simply a different approach.

To demonstrate this example I am creating a new sparse matrix:

```
from scipy.sparse.csc import csc_matrix
a = csc_matrix([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 10, 11], [0, 0, 0, 99]])
print(a)
```

Output:

```
(0, 0)  1
(1, 2)  10
(1, 3)  11
(2, 3)  99
```

To access this easily, like the way we access a list, I converted it into a list.

```
temp_list = []
for i in a:
    temp_list.append(list(i.A[0]))

print(temp_list)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 10, 11], [0, 0, 0, 99]]
```

This might look stupid, since I am creating a sparse matrix and converting it back, but there are some functions like **[TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)** and others that return a sparse matrix as output and handling them can be tricky. This is one way to extract data out of a sparse matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Coming into this rather late, but for those seeking a method for indexing into elements of a scipy sparse csr or csc matrix, we can convert the nonzero row, column, and data arrays into a pandas dataframe and extract the element from the data attribute of the matrix. This simple technique doesn't require conversion to a dense array.

Let's create sparse array.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, random
from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = default_rng()
rvs = stats.poisson(25, loc=10).rvs
A = random(5, 5, density=0.25, random_state=rng, data_rvs=rvs)
A.A
```

Output

```
array([[32.,  0., 32.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0., 29.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., 30.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0., 37., 30.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

The following function takes a sparse csr or csc matrix, as well as the desired nonzero row, and column indices.

```
def get_element(matrix, row, col):
    rows, cols = matrix.nonzero()
    d = {"row": rows, "col": cols, "data": matrix.data}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    element = df[(df["row"] == row) & (df["col"] == col)]["data"].values[0]
    return element
```

To index into A[3,2]:

```
get_element(A, row=3,col=2)
```

Output:
37.0